# request.env['omniauth.auth'] is getting nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, activeadmin, omniauth

So I was trying to set up Google  Omniauth2 authentication in Active Admin in Ruby on rails, my after the user clicks on his account on the google signup dialogue box it gets redirected to **root_path**
i.e. /

This is error I am getting in response or request

```
Started POST "/admin/auth/google_oauth2" for ::1 at 2022-02-20 02:07:04 +0530
D, [2022-02-20T02:07:04.882189 #137717] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/admin/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=e3435afeb73ff096cdf7c2fba4e9dff0c009f2d581b282f8&code=4%2F0AX4XfWg19pJcL4XrQkseJrAEYZawewR80PHY5oNFHBAbmXSNzhzy_HoMcFlRaE4UR6HiOw&scope=email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent" for ::1 at 2022-02-20 02:07:08 +0530
D, [2022-02-20T02:07:08.048851 #137717] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2022-02-20T02:07:08.203534 #137717] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! undefined method `bytesize' for {"client_id"=>"7345634785-5b43jhb53hb34jhbr43hjrb318egf1.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_secret"=>"XXXXXX-9oO4eKfhghdfjghfddfk-wfA", "grant_type"=>"authorization_code", "code"=>"4/0AX4XfWg19pJcL4XrQkseJrAEYZawewR80PHY5oNFHBAbmXSNzhzy_HoMcFlRaE4UR6HiOw", :redirect_uri=>"http://localhost:3000/admin/auth/google_oauth2/callback"}:Hash: NoMethodError, undefined method `bytesize' for {"client_id"=>"7345634785-5b43jhb53hb34jhbr43hjrb318egf1.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_secret"=>"XXXXXX-9oO4eKfhghdfjghfddfk-wfA", "grant_type"=>"authorization_code", "code"=>"4/0AX4XfWg19pJcL4XrQkseJrAEYZawewR80PHY5oNFHBAbmXSNzhzy_HoMcFlRaE4UR6HiOw", :redirect_uri=>"http://localhost:3000/admin/auth/google_oauth2/callback"}:Hash
Processing by AdminUsers::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"e3435afeb73ff096cdf7c2fba4e9dff0c009f2d581b282f8", "code"=>"4/0AX4XfWg19pJcL4XrQkseJrAEYZawewR80PHY5oNFHBAbmXSNzhzy_HoMcFlRaE4UR6HiOw", "scope"=>"email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid", "authuser"=>"0", "prompt"=>"consent"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 352)
```

After this control goes back to failure address

> config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
      Rails.application.credentials.google[:client_id],
      Rails.application.credentials.google[:secret_key],
      scope: 'email',
```

> app/models/admin_user.rb

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.google_data"] && session["devise.google_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> app/controller/admin/admin_users

```
class AdminUsers::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  # See https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/FAQ#rails-session-is-clobbered-after-callback-on-developer-strategy
  # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :google_oauth2

  def google_oauth2
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @admin_user = AdminUser.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    debugger.info "google_oauth2"
    if @admin_user.persisted?
      sign_in @admin_user#, event: :authentication # this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Google') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra) # Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def failure
    flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in. Please register or try signing in later.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I am getting request.env['omniauth.auth'] nil in faliure and not getting any output in google_oath2 method that means my control isn't going in google_oath2 callback but getting into faliure instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with oauth_2 default version

```
gem 'oauth2', '~> 1.4.9'
```

adding this to my gem file, then run `bundle install` solved the issue